# Как сделать нестандартные стрелки?

Tags: html, css

На CSS в макете, что первый, что второй блок сделан одним слоем:

[image: две стрелки] [image: стрелка вниз]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не понял, где возникли трудности у автора вопроса, поэтому нет смысла что-то объяснять. Лучше показать на примере:

```css
/* Кнопка */
button {
  display: grid; place-items: center;
  height: 124px; width: 124px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: #daad2c;
}

/* Стрелка */
.arrow {
  --arrow-size: 16px;
  --arrow-color: #583b95;
  font: italic bold var(--arrow-size)/1em 'Comic Sans MS', sans-serif;
  /*line-height: 1em;*/
  position: relative; z-index: 0;
  display: grid; place-items: center;
  height: 1.5em; width: 5.4375em;
  padding: 0 0.625em 0 0;
  border-radius: 0.1875em 0 0 0.1875em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: var(--arrow-color);
  background-clip: content-box;
}
.arrow::before,
.arrow::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; right: 0; z-index: -1;
  background-color: var(--arrow-color);
}
.arrow::before {
  padding: 1.15em;
  border-radius: 0.125em 0.25em;
  transform: translate(-0.33em, -50%) rotate(45deg);
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #0000 50%, var(--arrow-color) 50%);
}
.arrow::after {
  padding: 1.6em 0.125em;
  border-radius: 0.125em;
  transform: translate(-1.375em, -50%);
}

/* Варианты направления */
.arrow[arrow-dir="left"]  { transform: rotate(.5turn);  }
.arrow[arrow-dir="down"]  { transform: rotate(.25turn); }
.arrow[arrow-dir="up"]    { transform: rotate(.75turn); }
.arrow[arrow-dir="right"] { transform: rotate(0turn);   }
.arrow[arrow-dir="spin"]  { animation: spin 2s ease infinite; }

/* Анимация вращения */
@keyframes spin { to { transform: rotate(1turn); } }

body { margin: 0; min-height: 100vh; background-color: black; display: flex; justify-content: space-around; align-items: center; }
```

```html
<div class="arrow" arrow-dir="left" style="--arrow-size: 10px; --arrow-color: red;"></div>
<div class="arrow" arrow-dir="down" style="--arrow-size: 18px; --arrow-color: yellow;"></div>
<button><div class="arrow" arrow-dir="spin">GO!!!</div></button>
<div class="arrow" arrow-dir="up" style="--arrow-size: 4px; --arrow-color: green;"></div>
<div class="arrow" arrow-dir="right" style="--arrow-size: 36px; --arrow-color: blue;"></div>
```

*Код самой стрелки может быть короче и содержать только один псевдоэлемент, если не нужны скруглённые углы. Большая часть остального кода лишь для примера и может быть сокращена под конкретные задачи.*